# which event are called between wishlist and checkout cart in magento

Tags: magento

I am new in magento my question is that which events are called between wishlist and checkout cart in magento when press add all to cart button. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: hello check this links may be help you http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/ http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

Answer (score 2):

Quite a lot of events are called events that relate to page rendering, events that relate to loading models, events that relate to the cart addition itself. There is not definite list because any module can add its own events.

The best thing you can do is log all events being called and see the list of events specific to your install / configuration.

Edit `app/Mage.php`, look for `Mage::dispatchEvent` and add the following line to it:

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array()) {
    /** add the line below */
    Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```